Matplotlib LinearSegmentedColormap does not respect zero point colour
I have a custom colormap defined in matplotlib:
>>>from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
>>>OrWhBu = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('OrWhBu', np.array((
    (118,  21,  33),
    (145,  28,  19),
    (200,  42,  29),
    (225,  92,  51),
    (233, 137,  51),
    (247, 221, 118),
    (251, 241, 169),
    (255, 255, 205),
    (255, 255, 255),
    (239, 253, 255),
    (220, 254, 253),
    (140, 213, 235),
    (102, 177, 207),
    ( 76, 143, 165),
    ( 67,  80, 127),
    ( 33,  45, 108),
    ( 23,  45,  81)))/255
)

When I query the colour at the midpoint of the colormap, it does not return (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) as I would expect:
>>>OrWhBu(0.5)
(0.9980376046062891, 0.9997547005757862, 1.0, 1.0)

This is very similar to this question, however the accepted answer does not work in this case because my desired zero point is 0. Admittedly, this colour is very close to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), but when I plot a filled contour, the central bin colour is visibly off-white compared to the background:


The colormap is internally represented by N colors.  By default, N=256 which is an even number. There is no value at the exact half point. Only at positions 127 and 128. As you have an uneven number of input colors, the value for colormap index 127 goes a tiny bit towards orange, while the value for colormap index 128 goes a bit towards blue.
Choosing an odd N will map the central index exactly to white.
The following code tests these assumptions.  Note that a colormap behaves differently whether its input is of an integer type, or of a float type. A float f is interpreted as a value between 0 and 1, and the entry at position f // N  is returned.  An integer i is treated as an index into the colormap.
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = np.array((
    (118, 21, 33),
    (145, 28, 19),
    (200, 42, 29),
    (225, 92, 51),
    (233, 137, 51),
    (247, 221, 118),
    (251, 241, 169),
    (255, 255, 205),
    (255, 255, 255),
    (239, 253, 255),
    (220, 254, 253),
    (140, 213, 235),
    (102, 177, 207),
    (76, 143, 165),
    (67, 80, 127),
    (33, 45, 108),
    (23, 45, 81))) / 255

OrWhBu256 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('OrWhBu256', colors, N=256)
print('0.5 for map with 256 entries:', OrWhBu256(0.5))  # (0.9980315263360247, 0.9997539407920031, 1.0, 1.0)
for i in range(126, 130):
    print(f'entry {i}: {OrWhBu256(i)}')
'''
entry 126: (1.0, 1.0, 0.9815455594002307, 1.0)
entry 127: (1.0, 1.0, 0.9938485198000769, 1.0)
entry 128: (0.9980315263360247, 0.9997539407920031, 1.0, 1.0)
entry 129: (0.9940945790080739, 0.9992618223760092, 1.0, 1.0)
'''

OrWhBu255 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('OrWhBu255', colors, N=255)
print('0.5 for map with 255 entries:', OrWhBu255(0.5))  # (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)


Thanks for this answer! I found it significantly more helpful in understanding how the colormap actually works in Matplotlib than either the answer to the question I linked, or the official documentation for LinearSegmentedColormap.
